# There is no response in postman, I'm sending patch request but not receiving response in postman console?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

```
router.patch('/:productId', async (req, res, next) => {

    const id = req.params.productId;
    console.log(req.body)
    const product = await Product.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: id }, { $set: req.body })
})
```

I can see change into VSC console, but not in the postman.

Comment: There is no `res.status().send()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to send back a response! you can do that using `res.json({product})` if what you need is a json object back!